# Dúvida de implementação em Orientação a Objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou implementando o exercício conjunto de inteiros do livro **deitel 6ª edição**:

Crie a classe `IntegerSet`. Cada objeto `IntegerSet` pode armazenar inteiros no intervalo de 0 a 100. O conjunto é representado por um array de `boolean`. O elemento do `array[i]` é true se o inteiro `i` estiver no conjunto. O elemento do `array[j]` é false se o inteiro `j` não estiver no conjunto. O construtor sem argumento inicializa o `array` Java como 'conjunto vazio' (isto é, um conjunto cuja representação de `array` contém todos os valores `false`).

***Forneça os seguintes métodos***:

O método  `union` cria um terceiro conjunto que é a união teórica de dois conjuntos existentes (isto é, um elemento do terceiro `array` do conjunto é configurado como `true` se esse elemento for `true` em qualquer um dos conjuntos existentes ou em ambos; caso contrário, o elemento do terceiro conjunto é configurado como `false`).

O método `intersecction` cria um terceiro conjunto que é a intersecção teórica de dois conjuntos existentes (isto é, um elemento do array do terceiro conjunto é configurado como `false` se esse elemento for `false` em qualquer um ou em ambos os conjuntos existentes - caso contrário, o elemento do terceiro conjunto é configurado como `true`).

O método `insertElement` insere um novo inteiro `k` em um conjunto(configurando `a[k]` como `true`).

O método `deletElement` exclui o inteiro `m` (configurando `a[m]` como `false`).

O método `toSetString` retorna uma string contendo um conjunto com uma lista de números separados por espaços. Inclua somente os elementos que estão presentes no conjunto. Utilize `--` para representar um conjunto vazio.

O método `isEqualTo` determina se dois conjuntos são iguais.

Esse é o código que construí até agora, porém algumas dúvidas surgiram. Como posso declarar um único objeto `IntegerSet` no parâmetro e fazer a comparação para a união ou interseccao, isso é possível?

```
public class IntegerSet{
    private int positions;
    public boolean array[];


    public IntegerSet(){
        this.array = new boolean[101];
        }

    public boolean[] union(IntegerSet iSet1, IntegerSet iSet2){
        boolean tConjunto[] = new boolean[101];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(iSet1 || iSet2){
                tConjunto[i] = true;
            }
        return tConjunto;
        }
    }

    public boolean[] intersection(IntegerSet iSet1, IntegerSet iSet2) {
        boolean tConjunto[] = new boolean[101];
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(iSet1 && iSet2){
                tConjunto[i] = false;
            }
        return tConjunto;
        }
    }
    public void insertElement(int k){
        this.array[k] = true;
    }

    public void deletElement(int m){
        this.array[m] = false;
    }

    public String toSetString(){
        return "oi";
    }

   public boolean isEqualsTo(IntegerSet iSet1, IntegerSet iSet2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (iSet1 != iSet2) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A classe `IntegerSet` representa um conjunto, então - pelo que entendi - os métodos para união e intersecção deveriam ter estas assinaturas:

```
public IntegerSet intersecction(IntegerSet outro)

public IntegerSet union(IntegerSet outro)
```

Ou seja, eles recebem outro `IntegerSet` e retornam um outro `IntegerSet` contendo o resultado da intersecção (ou união). Por exemplo, `s3 = s1.union(s2)` - o método retorna um conjunto que é a união de `s1` com `s2` (e o resultado é atribuído à `s3`).

Outro detalhe é que a variável `positions` não é usada para nada. Se o tamanho for sempre o mesmo, vale mais criar uma "constante" (uma variável `static final`) para tal.

Além disso, os métodos para inserir e remover um elemento não devem receber o array como parâmetro. O array que você quer modificar é o que está declarado na própria classe, estes métodos podem receber apenas o índice que será modificado.

Uma alternativa de solução seria:

```
public class IntegerSet {

    private static final int TAMANHO = 101;

    private boolean array[];

    public IntegerSet() {
        this.array = new boolean[TAMANHO];
    }

    private IntegerSet(boolean values[]) {
        this.array = values;
    }

    // retorna a intersecção deste Set com outro
    public IntegerSet intersecction(IntegerSet outro) {
        boolean intersect[] = new boolean[TAMANHO];
        for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            intersect[i] = this.array[i] && outro.array[i];
        }
        return new IntegerSet(intersect);
    }

    // retorna a união deste Set com outro
    public IntegerSet union(IntegerSet outro) {
        boolean un[] = new boolean[TAMANHO];
        for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            un[i] = this.array[i] || outro.array[i];
        }
        return new IntegerSet(un);
    }

    public void insertElement(int pos) {
        this.array[pos] = true;
    }

    public void deletElement(int pos) {
        this.array[pos] = false;
    }

    public String toSetString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            if (this.array[i]) { // número i pertence ao set
                if (sb.length() == 0) {
                    sb.append(i);
                } else {
                    sb.append(" ").append(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.length() == 0 ? "--" : sb.toString();
    }

    // verifica se este set é igual a outro
    public boolean isEqualsTo(IntegerSet outro) {
        for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO; i++) {
            if (this.array[i] != outro.array[i]) {
                // achei um elemento diferente, os sets não são iguais
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Para a união e intersecção eu crio um terceiro array e vou preenchendo seus valores de acordo com as regras requisitadas. Como são valores booleanos, posso atribuir diretamente o resultado das operações `&&` e `||`. No caso, para intersecção eu usei `&&`:

```
intersect[i] = this.array[i] && outro.array[i];
```

Assim, se ambos (`this.array[i]` e `outro.array[i]`) forem `true` (ou seja, se o número `i` pertence a ambos os sets), então ele será `true` no terceiro array também. Para a união, eu uso `||`:

```
un[i] = this.array[i] || outro.array[i];
```

Nesse caso, se um dos dois for `true`, já é o suficiente para estar no terceiro array.

Repare também que criei um construtor privado para a classe:

```
private IntegerSet(boolean values[]) {
    this.array = values;
}
```

Assim, eu posso criar um set passando um array específico para o mesmo. Como é `private`, ele só pode ser usado dentro da classe - no caso, usei para passar o array que criei nos métodos para intersecção e união. Se quiser que qualquer pessoa possa criar um set com qualquer array, basta deixar o construtor `public` (mas nesse caso seria bom verificar o tamanho do array antes de setá-lo).

O método `toSetString()` percorre o array e só considera os que são `true`. É feita uma verificação adicional para saber se deve ter um espaço antes do número, além de uma outra verificação no final para saber se o conjunto é vazio.

E o método `isEqualsTo` recebe outro set e compara os respectivos arrays. Se encontrar algum diferente, já posso retornar que os sets não são iguais. Se chegar ao final do loop, é porque todos são iguais.

---

Testando:

```
IntegerSet s1 = new IntegerSet();
s1.insertElement(10);
s1.insertElement(20);
s1.insertElement(30);

IntegerSet s2 = new IntegerSet();
s2.insertElement(10);
s2.insertElement(15);
s2.insertElement(20);
s2.insertElement(25);

System.out.println("s1=" + s1.toSetString());
System.out.println("s2=" + s2.toSetString());
System.out.println("intersecção=" + s1.intersecction(s2).toSetString());
System.out.println("união=" + s1.union(s2).toSetString());
System.out.println("s1 e s2 iguais? " + s1.isEqualsTo(s2));

IntegerSet s3 = new IntegerSet();
s3.insertElement(30);
s3.insertElement(10);
s3.insertElement(20);
System.out.println("s1 e s3 iguais? " + s1.isEqualsTo(s3));

s3.deletElement(20);
System.out.println("s1 e s3 iguais? " + s1.isEqualsTo(s3));

System.out.println("set vazio: " + new IntegerSet().toSetString());
```

Saída:

```
s1=10 20 30
s2=10 15 20 25
intersecção=10 20
união=10 15 20 25 30
s1 e s2 iguais? false
s1 e s3 iguais? true
s1 e s3 iguais? false
set vazio: --
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada! você poderia me explicar como o método private IntegerSet(boolean values[]) está sendo utilizado no programa como um todo? e outra coisa como o método toSetString() só considera os que são true?

Comment: @JulianaDeMorais O construtor `private IntegerSet(boolean values[])` é usado nos métodos `intersection` e `union`, quando eu faço `new IntegerSet(intersect)` e `new IntegerSet(un)` (o array de boolean é passado como parâmetro, e ele passa a ser o array do novo set). O `toSetString` só considera os que são true porque eu faço `if (this.array[i])` (ou seja, se `this.array[i]` é true, ele entra no `if` e inclui o `i` na string)